# Enforce space between functions with Haskell linter

Tags: haskell, atom-editor, linter

I want to enforce a space of exactly two lines between my top-level function declarations in Haskell.

Is there any linter for Atom (or any other editor) that allows that?

Comment: maybe you can write an hlint rule to achieve that